# Do I need to download the Unity source code in order to use it?

Tags: unity-container

I looked unsuccessfully for a link for binary downloads for Unity.  Is the only option to download the source code from Codeplex and build it myself?

Comment: Are you referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203101.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2d24f179-e0a6-49d7-89c4-5b67d939f91b&displaylang=en